# Binary DataFrame to dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I am trying to convert a dataframe into a dictionary using python. The dataframe is similar as:

```
data_quim = {'Type':[1,2,3],'BCN':['X',np.nan,np.nan],'MAD':[np.nan,'X',np.nan],'MAT':['X',np.nan,'X']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data_quim)
df

   Type     BCN MAD MAT

0   1        X  NaN X
1   2       NaN X   NaN
2   3       NaN NaN X
```

I want to get a dictionary with this form:

```
{1:['BCN','MAT],
2:['MAD],
3:['MAT]}
```

I have tried to function to_dict(), with setting first 'Type' to index, but cannot get exactly what I want. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
(df.set_index('Type').stack()
   .reset_index(1)
   ['level_1'].groupby(level=0)
   .apply(list)
   .to_dict()
)
```

output:

```
{1: ['BCN', 'MAT'], 2: ['MAD'], 3: ['MAT']}
```

Or, using `apply`:

```
(df.set_index('Type')
   .apply(lambda s: list(s.dropna().index), axis=1)
   .to_dict()
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I really like @mozway's second answer for this specific problem but `apply` sometimes isn't fastest.  Since pandas is so flexible, you could also do this with `pd.melt` which is a very flexible way for transforming wide data to narrow data and lean on `groupby`.  This would be more helpful if you need to do something with more conditions/processing before putting it in the list (what if you have 'X','Y','NaN', and want to do something different with 'X' vs 'Y'):

```
df.melt(id_vars='Type')\
  .dropna()\
  .groupby('Type')\
  .agg({'variable': list})\
  .to_dict()['variable']
```

Or if you wanted to get out of pandas as quick as possible for some reason:

```
{
    row[0]: [
        label 
        for label, indicator in zip(df.columns[1:], row[1:]) 
        if indicator == 'X'
    ] 
    for row in df.values
}
```

The big picture is that this is a good problem for mapping the original wide table to a key-value pair for each 'X', and then reducing by key all of the values into a list.  Since your rows are already grouped by key, I really like @mozway's second suggestion.  My second suggestion is a way to do it outside of pandas that would also work well if you instead needed to work with a streaming iterator for each row.